# Probability problem of fishes in a lake

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Exercise**

In order to estimate the number $N$ of fishes in a lake, a fisherman executes the following procedure: in the first step, he captures $n$ fishes and after marking them, he returns them to the lake. In the second step, he captures $m$ fishes and counts the number of marked fishes.

1) Calculate the probability than in the second step there are exactly $k$ marked fishes.

2) Given a fixed $k$, find the value of $N$ that maximizes the previous probability.

This is what I thought for part 1):

First I call $A$ to the event described in 1). Given $k \leq n,m$ (because if not, this probability is $0$), we have $n$ marked fishes and $N-n$ unmarked fishes, so, the number of ways of picking $m$ fishes in order to get exactly $k$ marked fishes is ${n \choose k}{N-n \choose m-k}$, and the number of ways of 
picking $m$ fishes out of $N$ is ${N \choose m}$, putting all these together, we get $$P(A)=\dfrac{{n \choose k}{N-n \choose m-k}}{{N \choose m}}$$

2) If $P_{N,k}$ is the probability given in 1), I've tried to find $N$ for which the inequality $P_{N,k} \geq P_{N-1,k}$ doesn't hold, that means, $\dfrac{P_{N,k}}{P_{N-1,k}}<1$

Using 1), $\dfrac{P_{N,k}}{P_{N-1,k}}<1$ iff $\dfrac{(N-n)(N-m)}{(N-n-(m-k))N}<1$. This last inequality is true if and only if $\dfrac{nm}{k}<N$. Then, the maximum $N'$ that maximized the probabity of 1) is $N'=\dfrac{mn}{k}$ if this number is natural, and if not, $N'=\lfloor{\frac{mn}{k}}\rfloor$.

I would appreciate if someone could tell me if I commited any mistakes in my solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have got the first part correct. For the second part, you need to consider both directions of the inequality to prove that you have got a maximum; i.e., all values of $N$ either smaller than or larger than the one you calculated should *reduce* the probability.

Comment: Right, thanks! I have a doubt, I was not sure if the probability I've calculated in 1) was correct because of the following: why the number of ways of choosing $n$ fishes out of $N$ doesn't seem to affect the probability of choosing $m$ fishes out of $N$ such that this and that happen?

Comment: It doesn't affect the answer because you have already accounted for the $n$ fishes in the numerator $\binom{n}{k}\binom{N-n}{m-k}$. $n$ is assumed to be 'fixed' because you have already chosen the fishes and marked them.

Comment: [Experimentally](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hhaxixmo0e), $N = \frac{nm}{k}$ seems to be the peak, but this is a very good problem to prove.

Comment: If $\dfrac{nm}{k} = N$ then ${P_{N,k}}={P_{N-1,k}} $ so both give the maximum